# how to capture D3D window in windows 10 with c++

Tags: c++, windows, direct3d

I tried use gdi to capture certain window, it's ok for most window.
But to some window like "visual studio code", it doesn't work.
DX can't support capturing certain window.
How should I do? THANKS

```
    ::EnumWindows(EnumWindowsProc, NULL);
    if (hCapWnd == NULL)
    {
        return FALSE;
    }
    SwitchToThisWindow(hCapWnd, true);
    Sleep(1000);
    //HWND hDesktopWnd = GetDesktopWindow();
    HDC hDesktopDC = GetWindowDC(hCapWnd);
    HDC hCaptureDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hDesktopDC);
    SetStretchBltMode(hCaptureDC, COLORONCOLOR);
     RECT rc;
    ::GetWindowRect(hCapWnd, &rc);
    int width = rc.right - rc.left;
    int height = rc.bottom - rc.top;
     HBITMAP hCaptureBitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hDesktopDC, width, height);
     SelectObject(hCaptureDC, hCaptureBitmap);
     BOOL bRet = BitBlt(hCaptureDC, 0, 0, width, height, hDesktopDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
     Init(width, height);
     int nRet = GetDIBits(hCaptureDC, hCaptureBitmap, 0, height, buf, (BITMAPINFO*)&m_bitmapInfo, DIB_RGB_COLORS);

    static int n = 0;
    //if (n++ % 10 == 0) 
    {
       // std::string name = ustd::format_string("%s\\%d.bmp", ustd::get_program_path().c_str(), n);
        SaveBitmapToFile(hCaptureBitmap);
    }

    ReleaseDC(hCapWnd, hDesktopDC);
    DeleteDC(hCaptureDC);
    DeleteObject(hCaptureBitmap);
```